# How to store a password during one QGIS work session?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I'd like to get into qgis-plugin development, but am rather new to both python and QGIS development.

I intend to write a plugin which connects data from a mysql database to shapefiles. As the data is related to persons, I need a kind of login before accessing the data. To avoid the user from typing his password every time he invokes the script, I wonder if it is possible to retain values between calls of the script. In the python cookbook, I found global project settings - but that is not quite what I'm looking for as the values should be forgotten on closing QGIS.

I hope I made my intentions clear in my clumpy English and somebody could give me a hint with which way to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `classQGSCredentials` to set and get credentials:

http://qgis.org/api/classQgsCredentials.html